# FileNotFoundException in JUnit testing

Tags: java, filereader, filenotfoundexception

I have this line of code in my program

```
Map jsonFile = new Gson().fromJson(new FileReader("Metro_Transit_Bus_Stops.geojson"), Map.class);
```

When I run it from the main of the class I get no errors, it is able to read and parse through the json file.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        BSSDataWrangler dw = new BSSDataWrangler();
        List<Object> busStops = dw.createBusStop();
        System.out.println(busStops.size());
    }
```

However, when I call the method from my JUnit test method,

```
@Test
public void test1() {
        
BSSDataWrangler dw = new BSSDataWrangler();
        List<Object> busStops = dw.createBusStop();
        assertEquals(25, busStops.size());

    }
```

it gives me this error. Any idea why? Thank you!

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Metro_Transit_Bus_Stops.geojson (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Comment: I think it might be a JUnit issue as I tried making another class worked completely fine

Comment: I'd recommend refactoring this code. Unit tests should not depend on the file system, much less on relative paths. Make the code under test accept a `Reader` so that real life code can pass a `FileReader` and tests can pass any other `Reader` to have the code under test read from a memory location.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the compiler is not able to find the file that you have specified. You can try sharing the absolute path of the file from the src folder of the project.

in this line.

```
Map jsonFile = new Gson().fromJson(new FileReader("Metro_Transit_Bus_Stops.geojson"), Map.class);
```

Comment: Yeah changing it to the full path did fix it. But it is weird how the relative path works when I run it normally but when I use JUnit tests if I don't use the full path it throws the exception